# Unit Test or Integration Test in Spring Boot

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

I looked various tutorial online related to testing in `Spring Boot` and got confused by the way the tests were referred.

Some articles refer to controller tests that use `@WebMvcTest` annotation as `Unit Test` whereas some refer it as `Integration Test`. Not sure which one is correct.

Same questions applies to Repository layer test with `@DataJpaTest`.

I have following two tests written in my application, one for the controller and another one for the repository.

At the bottom I have some questions regarding both. Please guide.

**UserControllerTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void signUp() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/signup")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

**UserRepositoryTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void whenFindByName_thenReturnEmployee() {
        // given
        User u = new User();
        u.setName("ab");
        u.setEmail("ab@cd.com");
        entityManager.persistAndFlush(u);
        // when
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(1L);
        // then
        assertTrue(user.isPresent());
    }

}
```

My questions are:

1. Does the annotation `@WebMvcTest, @DataJpaTest` or `@SpringBootTest` determines the type of test (`Unit` or `Integration`) or is it the use of `@MockBean` within the test that determines it?
2. Assuming that `UserControllerTest.java` is a Unit test we are mocking the `userRepository` dependency here with `@MockBean private UserRepository userRepository` whereas in `UserRepositoryTest.java` we are autowiring it with  `@Autowired private UserRepository userRepository`. Why ??

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Why do you need spring to do unit testing? You can only use Mockito to do so without the need to start spring context. This is explained and discussed in details here: https://reflectoring.io/unit-testing-spring-boot/

It's also very confusing for me when it comes to using @MockBean! Is that considered a unit or an integration test?
In my opinion, even we're using a mocked bean, but we're still running within spring context and for me this is an integration test (as a unit test doesn't need any spring context to run within). Same site that Brandon mentioned considers @MockBean an integration test https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean.

[Image from above site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73ZWm.png)

From Brandon response: "Integration tests should not contain any mocking and both types of testing should be run separately."

What if you want to test an api starting from the controller all the way to DB, but you want to exclude other systems (like kafka or external Microservices)? How would you achieve this? You definitely need @MockBean. This is an integration test even it has mocked beans.

**In summary (based on my experience and after searching and reading a lot of contradicting info for days). Here is my opinion:**

- I would say, stay away from using spring for unit testing as much as possible and just use Mockito or another framework that doesn’t need spring context. For example, when writing a test for a service class to test some calculation logic, we don’t need spring context and this is a PURE unit test.
- We still can write PURE unit tests for controller classes. We can do that by calling the methods in the controller, then assert that these methods did what is expected (e.g. calling the right underlying methods with correct parameters ..etc). Basically the same way when writing a unit test for a service class. (Maybe these aren’t needed if it’s already gonna be covered in the  following types of tests?)
- We still can write pure unit tests for apis without any spring context. This described [here](https://medium.com/@phoenixrising_93140/unit-testing-spring-rest-controllers-via-mock-mvc-eb74490ee7f0). I tried and it worked for me. I'll paste the code at the end of the post.
- When running a test in spring context, this is considered an
  integration test even if you're using @MockBean. An example of this:
  if we want to test an api starting from the controller all the way to
  the DB, but we want to exclude other systems (like kafka, email, or
  other external Microservices). How would we achieve this? We
  definitely need @MockBean. This is an integration test even though it
  uses some mocked beans.
- *I think the most confusing part is when testing the api layer only*  **using spring as UserControllerTest in the question does** (I
  mean by that calling the api and making sure it returns the right
  status code and response format). Is that considered a unit test or
  an integration test? It is not a unit as unit tests don’t need spring
  context to run within. It is actually something in between unit and
  integration tests. This source explains this concept very well
  https://blog.marcnuri.com/mockmvc-spring-mvc-framework/  (more specifically MockMvc standalone setup) So I think,
  it goes back then to the team where to place these tests (in the unit
  test folder, in the integration test folder, in a separate folder?)
  Also a good naming convention is needed to be used to avoid any
  confusion with pure unit tests or pure integration tests for the same
  class. From what I saw, most teams consider those unit tests, but I
  am not sure if that is the best practice!

  ```
  //unit test to call an api using MockMvc and mockito only
  @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
  public class UserControllerTest {

  private MockMvc mockMvc;
  @Mock
  UserService userService;
  @InjectMocks
  UserController controllerUnderTest;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controllerUnderTest).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void testGetUser() throws Exception {

      //given:
      when(userService.getUser(.......)).thenReturn(....);

      //when:
      String url = "http://localhost:8081/api/ ....your url";

      //then:
      this.mockMvc.perform(get(url)).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
  ```

  }

Hope that helps and please let me know if there is any better opinion because I struggled a lot with that :)

Comment: thanks for the collaboration! My post had a very important mistake/typo regarding the "@MockBean", I have since edited my post! Only use "@MockBean" for integration testing! Thanks again.

Comment: Question 3 in your post. You're describing e2e testing. You're testing the web layer, service layer, AND the domain layer! Just write unit tests that mock the dependencies you described. If you're having to use @MockBean, it's an int test. Question 4. It depends on your use case...you can do either. A great resource is RestAssuredMockMVC which allows you to setup your tests as unit tests OR integration tests! Depends if you need the Spring web context or not. Super handy framework to have in your tool belt! Check out: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-mvc-rest-assured. Cheers fellas!

Comment: Thanks Brandon! This link is really great as it makes super clear and differentiates unit from integration tests https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-mvc-rest-assured  appreciate it!

Comment: For folks who prefer using MockMvc over rest assured, I edited the post and included a unit test that calls an api using MockMvc and Mockito only (no spring context). I tried and worked for me after I saw this https://medium.com/@phoenixrising_93140/unit-testing-spring-rest-controllers-via-mock-mvc-eb74490ee7f0

Answer (score 8):

*Unit tests run in isolation while integration tests bootstrap the Spring web context before execution starts.*

**UNIT TESTS**

Running in isolation will sometimes require that you mock your dependencies based on the class you are testing. By doing this, you're allowing yourself to test very specific test cases end-to-end without having to worry about the overhead of service or domain layers. Hence, using Mockito or more specifically, the Mockito.mock() method which mocks object classes and DOES NOT replace any objects on the web context such as @MockBean.

**INTEGRATION TESTS**

Whereas, integration testing focuses on integrating different layers of the application such as the database. In regards to databases, most people utilize an in memory database such as H2 to test their domain layers/repositories. Integration tests SHOULD not contain any mocking and both types of testing should be run separately. This isn't to say that integration tests can not contain any mocking, but it isn't common since you already have isolated unit tests that test the various layers of your application which contain mocked dependencies!

**E2E TESTS**

If you are testing your application from end-to-end, you're better off not mocking anything other than your data, with proper cleanup. Testing frameworks such as Cucumber are great for end-to-end testing. Why would you mock different layers, you already have unit tests for that type of testing!

Resources: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing and
https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean